# JQuery change new line to line break in TEXTAREA

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to change the new lines to line breaks in the `<TEXTAREA>`  but I'm failing to do so ...

I want to do this cause I take the value and append it to another `<TEXTAREA>` that is copied later on to the clipboard. When I copy to the clipboard, everything is set to a single line due to the `new line` in the `<textarea>`

Here is my code:

```
if(oInput.get(0).tagName == "TEXTAREA")
{
    temp = oInput.val();
    temp = temp.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
oInput.val() = temp.val();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(oInput.get(0).tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
    oInput.val(function(index, value) {
        return value.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try

```
temp.replace(/\n/g,'<br/>');
```

second thing is, change `oInput.val(temp);`

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yXhUV/

Comment: Thanks, this helped with the answer of Jed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the assignment to `oInput.val(temp);` i.e.

```
if(oInput.get(0).tagName == "TEXTAREA")
{
    temp = oInput.val();
    temp = temp.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    oInput.val(temp);
}
```